# ¿Como combinar un array asociativo con otro array asociativo en Laravel? Problema con colecciones

Tags: laravel

Estoy probando las colecciones, y tengo 2 dudas, la primera es  cuando he llegado al metodo where estoy teniendo problemas al usar LIKE.
Dada esta coleccion

```
    $coleccion = collection(  [
                        ['vehiculo' => 'toyota','propietario' => 'akio'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'opel','propietario' => 'rosari'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'mitsubishi','propietario' => 'ramon'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'reanult','propietario' => 'velvet'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'citroen','propietario' => 'anarella'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'mercedes','propietario' => 'juana'],
                        ['vehiculo' => ['cadillac','toyota'],'propietario' => 'sandro'],
                  ]);

 $resultado = $coleccion->where('vehiculo','LIKE','"%opel%"');

dd($resultado)
```

La variable resultado la he probado de varios modos y en ninguno de ellos me saca ningún resultado

```
$resultado = $coleccion->where('vehiculo','LIKE',"%opel%");

 $resultado = $coleccion->where('vehiculo','LIKE','%opel%');

 $resultado = $coleccion->where('vehiculo','LIKE','"%op%"');

 $resultado = $coleccion->where('vehiculo','like','"%opel%"');

 $resultado = $coleccion->where('vehiculo','"%opel%"');
```

.
Si esto lo uso usando un modelo, me funciona pero de este modo no.

---

Mi segunda duda es la que abre este post, me gustaria combinar  en cada uno de los arrays otra clave con otro valor, he probado usando combine, y merge y algo estoy haciendo mal que no me lo combina, simplemente me lo añade al final como una clave mas.

Partiendo de la misma coleccion,

```
$coleccion = collection(  [
                            ['vehiculo' => 'toyota','propietario' => 'akio'],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'opel','propietario' => 'rosari'],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'mitsubishi','propietario' => 'ramon'],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'reanult','propietario' => 'velvet'],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'citroen','propietario' => 'anarella'],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'mercedes','propietario' => 'juana'],
                            ['vehiculo' => ['cadillac','toyota'],'propietario' => 'sandro'],
                      ]);
```

He probado asi

```
$combinados = $coleccion->merge([0 => ['cilindraje' => 100],1 => ['cilindraje' => 1000],2 => ['cilindraje' => 200], 3 => ['cilindraje' => 350],4 => ['cilindraje' => 488],5 => ['cilindraje' => 665],6 => ['cilindraje' => 147]]);
```

y asi

```
$combinados = $coleccion->merge( ['cilindraje' => 100], ['cilindraje' => 1000],['cilindraje' => 200],  ['cilindraje' => 350], ['cilindraje' => 488], ['cilindraje' => 665],['cilindraje' => 147]]);
```

y no me funciona.
Como digo el resultado final deberia ser este

```
 $coleccion = collection(  [
                            ['vehiculo' => 'toyota','propietario' => 'akio','cilindraje' => 100],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'opel','propietario' => 'rosari',cilindraje' => 1000],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'mitsubishi','propietario' => 'ramon',cilindraje' => 200],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'reanult','propietario' => 'velvet',cilindraje' => 350],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'citroen','propietario' => 'anarella',cilindraje' => 488],
                            ['vehiculo' => 'mercedes','propietario' => 'juana',cilindraje' => 665],
                            ['vehiculo' => ['cadillac','toyota'],'propietario' => 'sandro',cilindraje' => 147],
                      ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira para lo primero puedes hacer usar el filter, seria algo como esto:

```
$coleccion = collect(  [
                    ['vehiculo' => 'toyota','propietario' => 'akio'],
                    ['vehiculo' => 'opel','propietario' => 'rosari'],
                    ['vehiculo' => 'mitsubishi','propietario' => 'ramon'],
                    ['vehiculo' => 'reanult','propietario' => 'velvet'],
                    ['vehiculo' => 'citroen','propietario' => 'anarella'],
                    ['vehiculo' => 'mercedes','propietario' => 'juana'],
                    ['vehiculo' => ['cadillac','toyota'],'propietario' => 'sandro'],
              ]);

    $resultado = $coleccion->filter(function($value,$key){

        $vehiculo = $value["vehiculo"];

        if(is_array($vehiculo)){
            $resultado = collect($vehiculo)->filter(function($value1,$key1){
                return str_contains($value1,"opel");
            });
            return $resultado->isNotEmpty();
        } else {
            return str_contains($vehiculo,"opel");
        }
    });
```

Y para lo segundo, puedes usar el map, seria asi:

```
$coleccion = collect(  [
                        ['vehiculo' => 'toyota','propietario' => 'akio'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'opel','propietario' => 'rosari'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'mitsubishi','propietario' => 'ramon'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'reanult','propietario' => 'velvet'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'citroen','propietario' => 'anarella'],
                        ['vehiculo' => 'mercedes','propietario' => 'juana'],
                        ['vehiculo' => ['cadillac','toyota'],'propietario' => 'sandro'],
                  ]);

    $coleccion2 = collect([['cilindraje' => 100], ['cilindraje' => 1000],['cilindraje' => 200],  ['cilindraje' => 350], ['cilindraje' => 488], ['cilindraje' => 665],['cilindraje' => 147]]);

    $resultado = $coleccion->map(function($value,$key) use ($coleccion2) {
        return collect($value)->merge($coleccion2[$key])->toArray();
    });
```

Comment: En cuanto a lo segundo funciona perfecto, pero el primero no acabo de comprenderlo bien(aunque funcionar funciona), no sé exactamente que recoge el $vehiculo del primer filter, he hecho varias pruebas y me saca la misma coleccion de arriba,de todos modos y aunque estoy muy agradecido por el tiempo que te has tomado en ayudarme con la duda, sigo sin comprender por que sigue sin funcionar el metodo where o el metodo like, uso la version 5.2, pero he mirado la documentacion y en la 5.2 si estan ambos metodos

Comment: Es que en tu código el vehículo aveces puede ser un array, entonces si es un array y se utiliza el `str_contains` generaria error, por eso se hace la validación y si el vehículo es un array se aplica un filter y se valida si dentro de ese array hay algún valor con la palabra opel.

Answer (score 1):

En vez de usar `merge` a secas deberías usar `array_merge`, te adjunto un ejemplo para que lo pruebes:

```
$array1 = array("id1" => "value1");

$array2 = array("id2" => "value2", "id3" => "value3", "id4" => "value4");

$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2/*, $arrayN, $arrayN*/);
$array4 = $array1 + $array2;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array3);
var_dump($array4);
echo '</pre>';
```